# Can you change the probability of a number coming up?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 3 die, each with 13 sides. You have to "roll" them until you get all three to be the same value (shown below).

```
ct = 1
import random
min = 1
max = 13

roll_again = "yes"

while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y" or roll_again == "":
    print "This is attempt number: ", + ct
    print "Now, rolling the dice..."
    print "The values are...."
    die1 = random.randint(min, max)
    die2 = random.randint(min, max)
    die3 = random.randint(min, max)
    print die1
    print die2
    print die3
    ct += 1
    if die1 == die2:
        if die2 == die3:
            print "Congrats! You win! hooray! You got it on attempt number ", + ct
            ct = 1
    roll_again = raw_input("Roll the dice again? ")
```

This all works fine,

[image: Here it is running after I got three numbers in a row...]

but I wanted the 1 face to be able to come up 5 times more than the rest (like a weighted die), and the face 13 to come up .5 times than the others (excluding the 1 value of course). Is this possible in Python 2.7?

Comment: What you could do is set up the `random.randint()` with a larger bound, and then return a desired result depending on the range of the number the generated number is in, so say if you want `1` to appear more often, you could set `randint`'s bounds to `(1, 11)` and count everything greater than a `6` to be a `1`. (not sure if this is too confusing for you to understand)

Comment: You could create a population with 10 `1`s, 1 `13` and 2 of everything else and then use `random.sample`  or `random.choice`

Comment: _Thanks a ton_! I think either of these would work!

Answer (score 3):

I once posted [an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358968/how-do-i-generate-random-letters-in-java-based-on-probability/12359384#12359384) (albeit in Java) in which someone wanted to choose letters of the alphabet with varying probabilities. You could take either of the approaches I suggested there.

The most general approach is to calculate the probability of choosing each number. You might have a list of (number, probability) tuples, for example

```
choices = [(1, 0.2), (2, 0.05), (3, 0.3113), ...]
```

and then you can make your random choice by choosing a random number between 0 and 1, iterating over the list, adding up probabilities as you go, and when you reach a sum which is larger than the random number you chose, stop and return the corresponding choice.

```
def random_choice(choices):
    r = random.random()
    cdf = 0
    for number, cumulative_probability in choices:
        cdf += cumulative_probability
        if r < cdf:
            return number
    return choices[-1][0]
```

(Note that `itertools.accumulate()` doesn't exist in Python 2, otherwise you could use that here.)

If you happen to be using Numpy, it has this functionality built in as `numpy.random.choice(numbers, p=probabilities)`.

If all your probabilities are multiples of a certain value, though, you might be better off using `random.choice()`. To do this, you'd create a list of the possible choices *without* probabilities, repeating each one enough to get the relative proportions you want. For example,

```
choices = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
```

would cause `1` to be three times as likely as `2` or `4`, and `3` to be twice as likely as `2` or `4`. Then just call `random.choice(choices)` each time you want to roll the die.

In your case, the second approach seems well suited, but you could use either. I'll leave it to you to figure out the proper definition of `choices` for your case. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the tool you're looking for is [numpy.random.choice()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

This tool allows you to generate a number following a non equiprobable probability law by giving list of the probability of all events as parameter

```
probability_A = 0.1
probability_B = 0.5
probability_C = 0.4

print(numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(1, 4), p = [probability_A, probability_B, probability_C]))
```

In your situation, you first need to calculate the probabilities.

If you know that the number "1" has a weight of 5 and the number "13" a weight of five, you can generate a vector (a list in Python language) this way:

```
weights = [5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5]

probabilities = [weight/sum(weights) for weight in weights]
```

And finally

```
numpy.random.choice(numpy.arange(1, 14), p = probabilities)
```